# better or more efficient solution for combining DataFrames, fillna and thinning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I already have a solution how to get to the desired result, but for me it seems as if my solution is far away from optimal.
Now describing the Situation:
Given two differens Pandas DataFrames each having timestamps as indices (from synchronized clocks). For further description taking these visualisations and descriptors

```
Table 1
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| ts1 |  m1  |  m2  | ... |  mi  |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| t_1 | m1_1 | m2_1 | ... | mi_1 |
| ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| t_k | m1_k | m2_k | ... | mi_k |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+

Table 2
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| ts2 |  s1  |  s2  | ... |  sn  |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| s_1 | s1_1 | s2_1 | ... | si_1 |
| ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| s_k | s1_p | s2_p | ... | si_p |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
```

The timestamps ts1 and ts2 are most likely different but they intersect each other.

I need to construct a result table of the form

```
Result Table
+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
| ts1 |  m1  |  m2  | ... |  mi  |  s1  |  s2  | ... |  si  |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
| t_1 | m1_1 | m2_1 | ... | mi_1 | z1_1 | z2_1 | ... | zi_1 |
| ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| t_k | m1_k | m2_k | ... | mi_k | z1_k | z2_k | ... | zi_k |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+
```

and the values `z` given in the table should each be the last (meaning over time thus using the timestamp) valid entry for the given data values in `s` equal of before the timestamp of the actual row. (I hope that could be understood.)

My solution reads:

```
# Combining data
ResultTable=pandas.concat([Table1, Table2]).sort_index()
# retrieving last valid entries for s
ResultTable.s1.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
ResultTable.s2.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
...
ResultTable.si.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
# removing unneeded timestamps `s_1 ... s_k` in result
# many ideas howto do that (deleting rows with NaN in m columns for example)
# please tell me, what would be most efficient?
```

Regarding the question for Efficiency - some Details on the sizes.
In my simple example I have 4.000.000 rows in Table 1 and 8 columns (might grow to 50).
Table 2 consists of about 1.000.000 rows and 85 columns.

WOW - `jezrael` solved that fast by his hint for `merge_asof` leading to a solution in just one line of code reading

```
test2=pandas.merge_asof(Table1.sort_index(), Table2.sort_index(),
                        left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another code should be simplify:

```
#if ts2 is column
cols2 = Table2.columns.difference(['ts2'])
#if ts2 is index
#cols2 = Table2.columns
ResultTable[cols2] = ResultTable[cols2].ffill()
```

instead:

```
ResultTable.s1.fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)
ResultTable.s2.fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)
...
ResultTable.si.fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)
```

---

If want delete NaNs in columns `m` use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) for identify `NaN`s, check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `NaN`s per row and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if ts2 is column
cols1 = Table1.columns.difference(['ts1'])
#if ts1 is index
#cols1 = Table1.columns

m = ResultTable[cols1].notnull().all(axis=1)

ResultTable = ResultTable[m]
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(45)


rng = (pd.date_range('2017-03-26', periods=3).tolist() + 
      pd.date_range('2017-04-01', periods=2).tolist() +
      pd.date_range('2017-04-08', periods=3).tolist() + 
      pd.date_range('2017-04-13', periods=2).tolist())
Table1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10)), index=rng).add_prefix('m') 
Table1.index.name = 'ts1'
print (Table1)
            m0  m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8  m9
ts1                                               
2017-03-26   3   0   5   3   4   9   8   1   5   9
2017-03-27   6   8   7   8   5   2   8   1   6   4
2017-03-28   8   4   6   4   9   1   6   8   8   1
2017-04-01   6   0   4   9   8   0   9   2   6   7
2017-04-02   0   0   2   9   2   6   0   9   6   0
2017-04-08   8   8   0   6   7   8   5   1   3   7
2017-04-09   5   9   3   2   7   7   4   9   9   9
2017-04-10   9   7   2   7   9   4   5   7   9   7
2017-04-13   6   2   7   7   6   6   3   6   0   7
2017-04-14   4   9   3   5   7   3   5   5   7   1
```

---

```
rng = (pd.date_range('2017-03-27', periods=3).tolist() + 
      pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=2).tolist() +
      pd.date_range('2017-04-06', periods=3).tolist() + 
      pd.date_range('2017-04-10', periods=2).tolist())
Table2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10)), index=rng).add_prefix('s') 
Table2.index.name = 'ts2' 
print (Table2)
            s0  s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9
ts2                                               
2017-03-27   0   2   1   9   2   3   9   6   3   6
2017-03-28   1   9   1   7   4   0   2   1   1   4
2017-03-29   2   2   2   5   3   6   7   5   6   5
2017-04-03   2   8   7   1   2   7   9   6   4   5
2017-04-04   4   5   4   1   3   7   0   5   0   6
2017-04-06   5   8   0   1   9   9   2   4   4   0
2017-04-07   8   2   8   9   7   5   4   3   2   5
2017-04-08   7   9   2   5   8   0   8   9   4   0
2017-04-10   2   5   1   2   1   4   2   3   7   0
2017-04-11   2   0   8   8   6   8   7   5   2   9
```

---

```
ResultTable=pd.concat([Table1, Table2]).sort_index()

cols2 = Table2.columns
ResultTable[cols2] = ResultTable[cols2].ffill()

cols1 = Table1.columns
m = ResultTable[cols1].notnull().all(1)

ResultTable = ResultTable[m]
```

---

```
print (ResultTable)
             m0   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5   m6   m7   m8   m9   s0   s1   s2  \
2017-03-26  3.0  0.0  5.0  3.0  4.0  9.0  8.0  1.0  5.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   
2017-03-27  6.0  8.0  7.0  8.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  1.0  6.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   
2017-03-28  8.0  4.0  6.0  4.0  9.0  1.0  6.0  8.0  8.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  1.0   
2017-04-01  6.0  0.0  4.0  9.0  8.0  0.0  9.0  2.0  6.0  7.0  2.0  2.0  2.0   
2017-04-02  0.0  0.0  2.0  9.0  2.0  6.0  0.0  9.0  6.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0   
2017-04-08  8.0  8.0  0.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  5.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  8.0  2.0  8.0   
2017-04-09  5.0  9.0  3.0  2.0  7.0  7.0  4.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  7.0  9.0  2.0   
2017-04-10  9.0  7.0  2.0  7.0  9.0  4.0  5.0  7.0  9.0  7.0  7.0  9.0  2.0   
2017-04-13  6.0  2.0  7.0  7.0  6.0  6.0  3.0  6.0  0.0  7.0  2.0  0.0  8.0   
2017-04-14  4.0  9.0  3.0  5.0  7.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  7.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  8.0   

             s3   s4   s5   s6   s7   s8   s9  
2017-03-26  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2017-03-27  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2017-03-28  9.0  2.0  3.0  9.0  6.0  3.0  6.0  
2017-04-01  5.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  5.0  6.0  5.0  
2017-04-02  5.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  5.0  6.0  5.0  
2017-04-08  9.0  7.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  5.0  
2017-04-09  5.0  8.0  0.0  8.0  9.0  4.0  0.0  
2017-04-10  5.0  8.0  0.0  8.0  9.0  4.0  0.0  
2017-04-13  8.0  6.0  8.0  7.0  5.0  2.0  9.0  
2017-04-14  8.0  6.0  8.0  7.0  5.0  2.0  9.0
```

---

Another solution should be [merging asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-asof).

Comment: your ffill() does a quite good Job. Cool idea. the dropna is not working the way I want to. I'd like to delete the rows in the result where there are NaNs in the columns of `m` resulting in having only the timestamps of table 1 in the result. Now reading asof and being impressed as that seems to be my solution.

Comment: Hmmm, I test now drop by rows and it doen not work nice, so I edit answer. Give me a time please.

Comment: I am thinking about your requirement - `where there are NaNs in the columns of m resulting in having only the timestamps of table 1 in the result`. I test it and there are never `NaN`s in `m` column for index of `Table1`, only for `Table2`. So remove rows from `m` by `NaN`s is impossible. Or something missing?

Comment: I now test it again and solution for remove NaNs has to be changed. I also add my test data, please check if all working nice.

Comment: I now read your comment in question ;) So no problem, `merge_asof` is reallyu good  ;)

Comment: I accepted you answer as merge_asof if perfect for me.  Regarding your question: Of course there would never ever be a NaN in an index. I meant removing those rows without data in the m-columns (beeing those generated by the concat from those timestamps out of Table2). But that is no longer of interest, as merge_asof if a quick hit. Thanks

Comment: Super, glad can help!